# Windows 8.1 setup

Tags: windows-8.1

I am installing Windows 8.1 from Windows 7 Ultimate by Windows 8.1 setup exe.

But, after entering the keys- (Your product keys checks out), it says "We can't connect right now ". Check your internet connection.

But internet connection is OK. What's the problem. Please help.

I want to tell here that but when I install Windows 8 pro from Windows 7 Ultimate or same PC, it starts installing/downloading. But it is creating problem only with Windows 8.1.

Please help.

Comment: maybe the servers are busy, do you have legit key?

Comment: Hi !

I got the key from a friend.

The key is good and valid. But i don't know whether it's legitimate.

But the problem i am facing is internet connection error ?

You mean to suggest that this error is due illegitimate key ?

Comment: take a ethernet cable and connect directly to you modem

Comment: it could be that soft firewall or hosts file is blocking your communication with microsoft servers...

Comment: Just uninstalled NIS.

Comment: so, it works now?